# Syntax for importing libraries, specifically matplotlib 3.0.2

Tags: python-3.x

I'd imagine this is a simple question, but why is (Python 3.7.1)

```
import matplotlib.cm
```

not the same as

```
from matplotlib import cm
```

?

Having tried the first method I get this error when calling the module:

```
NameError: name 'cm' is not defined
```

The second method works just fine. Is this a subtlety in the import statement or in the nature of a module?

Comment: use `import  matplotlib.cm as cm` then try calling `cm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case you import only part of the `matplotlib` module but maintain the namespace `matplotlib.cm` - so you have to use the lengthy namespace to access `cm`.

In the second case you import only part of the `matplotlib` module into `cm` namespace.

Effectively, to get to `ScalarMappable` (an example) class in `matplotlib.cm` you have to use:

1. `matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable`
2. `cm.ScalarMappable`