# import or from for matplotlib and similar libraries

Tags: python, matplotlib, import

i often see this:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

but in the past i have tended to use this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

i always thought that the second method of importing is clearer (and shorter). I notice from this question ([Syntax for importing libraries, specifically matplotlib 3.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53597707/syntax-for-importing-libraries-specifically-matplotlib-3-0-2)) where the function is short that the `from` method might be preferable.

Outside of the `namespace`, is there a fundamental difference between the two and if so, what ?

Comment: They should be equivalent in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

- Use from import to target a specific member (or members) of the module
- Use import to import the module as a whole

Also the use of the first one (from x import y) is faster, you only have one lookup
instead of two lookup when using the other approach ( one lookup for the module name and one for the function

Comment: so i understand that you assert that `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt` is faster. Would the namespace not make them equal as both point to the same ?

Comment: I don't think so, because (from x import y) it does one lookup at x and tave one target is Y , there is no need to iterate all modules inside x
Meanwhile (import x) : two lookups : one for lib X and one for all the modules inside it